# Map a ranking over an array of positive scores

Tags: ruby, haskell

I have a list of positive scores:

```
[98.5, 85, 50, 50, 23, 0, 0, 0]
```

I would like to assign ranks to these scores:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

When two consecutive scores have the same value, they get the same rank.
Any idea how to solve this in a functional fashion?

(*posted in Haskell and Ruby because I think both solutions would be feasible and can be ported*)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Ruby:

```
a = [98.5, 85, 50, 50, 23, 0, 0, 0]
sorted = a.sort.uniq.reverse
a.map{|e| sorted.index(e) + 1}
# => [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 6):

Haskell:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)
import Data.Function (on)

rank, rank' :: [Double] -> [Int]

rank ls = mapMaybe (fmap (+1) . (`elemIndex` sorted)) ls
  where sorted = reverse . nub $ sort ls

-- Or Fixnum's faster solution
rank' = map fst . sortBy (compare `on` snd)
      . concat . zipWith (\n -> map (n,)) [1..]
      . groupBy ((==) `on` snd)
      . sortBy (flip compare `on` snd) . zip [1::Int ..]
```

Interestingly, `rank` is pretty much sawa's answer. `nub` <=> `uniq` and `elemIndex` <=> `index`.

Comment: I also noticed that correlation. And `reverse` is just the same.

Comment: @sawa I was originally slightly dubious of OPs "porting haskell to ruby and vice versa" but it seems reasonably feasible haha. Now it just turns into a popularity contest between ruby and haskell

Comment: I do not know much about haskell, but I heard it is mathematically beautiful. Maybe the OP could have added lisp.

Comment: @GuaranaJoe I think that was sarcasm :)

Comment: This solution is slightly dubious since the use of `elemIndex` makes it quadratic in the number of scores ... I suggest `\scores -> concat . zipWith (map . const) [1..] . group . sortBy (flip compare) $ scores`.  Of course, @sawa's Ruby solution seems to have the same problem ... ;)

Comment: @Fixnum Can you elaborate on what you mean by "quadratic in the number of scores"?

Comment: @sawa - the time complexity: try with 100000 scores ;)

Comment: @Fixnum Yep, I was going for the "most obvious solution" here. I do like your answer though, would you mind if I added it to the answer above (with proper attribution)? or would you like to post it as it's own answer

Comment: @jozefg My comment is CC-licensed, go ahead :)

Comment: @Fixnum this is not the same solution. If you need to sort the scores, then you assume they may not be ordered. Your solution doesn't output the ranks of the original scores - it outputs the ranks of the _sorted_ scores.

Comment: @Fixnum I'm sorry about that, I couldn't find a way to merge an edit once it was rejected.. not sure why it was though

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [98.5, 85, 50, 50, 23, 0, 0, 0]
```

```
a.uniq.
  sort_by(&:-@).
  each_with_index.
  with_object({}) { |(x,i),h| h[x] = i+1 }.
  values_at(*a)
```

The most demanding operation is [Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) so this calculation has a computational complexity of O(n*log(n)) where `n = a.size`. @sawa's answer, by comparison, has a computational complexity of O(n*n). I don't know Haskell so cannot comment on the computational complexity of those answers.

See also [Numeric#-@](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Numeric.html#method-i-2D-40) and [Hash#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-values_at).

Answer (score 2):

Do we assume the scores are already sorted or not?

Here's how to solve it, if they cannot be assumed sorted:

```
Prelude Data.List Data.Function> let f = (const .) . (,) :: a -> b -> c -> (a,b)
Prelude Data.List Data.Function> let sor s = sortBy ((flip compare) `on` snd) s
Prelude Data.List Data.Function> let rank scores = map fst . sor . concat . 
        zipWith (map . uncurry . f) [1..] . groupBy ((==) `on` snd) . 
        sor . zip [1,0..] $ scores
Prelude Data.List Data.Function> rank [11,13,13,12]
[3,1,1,2]
```

First, attach a reverse index to each score. Then sort in descending order by the second projection of the tuple. Grouping by the second projection gives us a list of lists of scores that must have the same rank. Zipping with the list of ranks assigns rank 1 to the biggest number. By using function `f` we at the same time discard the actual score, making the tuples a pair of (rank,reverse index). Now need to sort these tuples in descending order of the reverse index, and get the first projection - the rank.

Answer (score 1):

If they are already sorted,
**Recursive**

```
eqNext (x:xs@(y:_)) acc = 
    let acc1 = if x == y then acc else acc + 1 in 
    acc1 : eqNext xs acc1
eqNext _ _ = []

els = 1 : eqNext ls 1
```

Let's check:

```
> let ls = [98.5, 85, 50, 50, 23, 0, 0, 0]
> els
[1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5]
```

the same **Non-recursive**:

```
els = snd $ mapAccumL accF (0,0) ls
     where
      accF(ac,prev) b = let a1 = if ac == 0 || b /= prev then ac + 1 else ac in 
        ((a1,b), a1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Ruby answer :)

```
data = [98.5, 85, 50, 50, 23, 0, 0, 0, 85]
data.map{|value| data.select{|item| item > value }.size + 1 }
```

`=> [1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 2]`

Comment: This cannot be correct as the computed array can have no element greater than `5`, since `data` contains only `5` unique values. For your value of `data` it should return `[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 2]`.